# Why Future(Failure(new Exception)) returns Success instead of failure?

Tags: scala, exception, future, futuretask

I was trying the following and thinking that I'll get a failure

```
val failure = Future { Failure(new Exception) }
```

but instead I got

```
Future(Success(Failure(java.lang.Exception)))
```

Can anyone answer why?

Comment: You can check that the type of `failure` is something like **Future[Try[Nothing]]**, so it is a future of a try, in this case us a successful future of a failed try. Note that, a future of a try rarely makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Future.failed`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#failed%5BT%5D(exception:Throwable):scala.concurrent.Future%5BT%5D) can create a failed future, for example

```
Future.failed(new Exception)
```

or `throw` inside the future

```
Future(throw new Exception)
```

or call [`Future.fromTry`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#fromTry%5BT%5D(result:scala.util.Try%5BT%5D):scala.concurrent.Future%5BT%5D)

```
Future.fromTry(Failure(new Exception))
```

however

```
Future(Failure(new Exception))
```

does not represent a failed future because

```
Failure(new Exception)
```

is, despite possibly misleading names, just a regular value, for example,

```
val x = Failure(new Exception)
val y = 42
Future(x)
Future(y)
```

so `Future(x)` is a successful future for the same reason `Future(y)` is a successful future.

You can think of `Future` as a kind of async try-catch, so if you are not throwing inside the try

```
try {
  Failure(new Exception) // this is not a throw expression
} catch {
  case exception =>      // so exception handler does not get executed
}
```

then catch handler does not get executed.